# How come doesObjectExist and listObjects do not agree on S3's Java API?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've got a S3 bucket `demo` with an object inside it `demo/somefolder`. When I call `s3.doesObjectExists("demo", "somefolder")` it returns false. However, when I call `s3.listObjects("demo", "somefolder")`, the `ObjectListing` that is returned has references to a list of `S3ObjectSummary`.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: S3 is pretty open about being eventually consistent. You could just be experiencing the effects of that. Does the problem still exist if you repeat the calls after a few seconds or minutes?

Comment: The observation holds after a few hours of programmatically creating objects; I do not think it is an eventually consistent issue with S3.

Answer (score 5):

I assume from the name `somefolder` that the "object" you describe is a "folder" rather than a file.

```
doesObjectExist(String bucketName, String objectName)
```

This tests for a specific object with key `objectName`.

```
listObjects(String bucketName, String prefix)
```

This returns a list of all objects whose key begins with `prefix`.

These are two entirely different tests.

*If* you created a folder *using the S3 console*, then `s3.doesObjectExists("demo", "somefolder/")` would be true -- note the tailing slash -- but "folders" in S3 do not exist as a meaningful entity, and this is not actually a valid use of `s3.doesObjectExist()`.

The console will display the folder `somefolder` for only one reason: because one or more objects exist in the bucket with the key prefix `somefolder/`.  But to facilitate navigation in a bucket with no structure, the console allows you to create the appearance of a structure by "creating folders"... which actually creates a 0-byte object with `/` appended to the end of whatever name you provided (but the console suppresses the display of this object itself). 
 These objects serve no purpose other than console navigation.  A programmatically-uploaded object with key `pics/cat.jpg` will still cause the `pics` "folder" to appear in the console, with no need to have created that placeholder folder-like object, first... so the presence or absence of these objects is not a meaningful test for whether there is such a "folder" in the bucket.

Comment: Trying `somefolder` versus `somefolder/` has the same effect. The object `somefolder` was not created through the S3 web UI, but programmatically through the Java SDK; will that make a difference?

Comment: If it's really an object, not a pseudo-folder, then it should not make a difference how it was created... but `doesObjectExist` requires the exact object key, while `listObjects` will return results with the keys where *string* is the key prefix.  If you find it's still inconsistent, you'll want check the bucket logs to see what requests are being sent to the bucket in each case.